# Angular embed view as peer to current component

Tags: angular

I'm wanting to do this in my HTML:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <expandable-tree-row [columns]="cols" [data]="row"></expandable-tree-row>
</tr>
```

In the `ExpandableTreeRowComponent` I used a `ViewContainerRef` so that the `td` tags are placed as a direct child of the `tr` element, like so:

```js
constructor(public readonly container: ViewContainerRef, private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.columns.forEach(x => this.container.createEmbeddedView(x.template))
    this.cdr.detectChanges()
}
```

That's adding each column's template properly, and in the correct location.  But now I still have the problem that the very first child of the `tr` element is the empty `<expandable-tree-row>` and so that messes up the table output by essentially shifting all of the columns one to the right.

How do I get rid of that first "bad" element now?

If instead I make it a directive and place on the `tr` element, like so:

```html
<tr expandable-tree-row [columns]="cols"></tr>
```

then visually it looks right, but the generated HTML technically is wrong as it ends up like this:

```html
<tr>...</tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<tr>...</tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
```

In other words, the `td` elements aren't children of the `tr` elements.

Comment: try transforming it into component with `tr[expandable-tree-row]` selector and such template `<ng-container *ngFor="let x of columns"><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="x.template"></ng-container>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the attribute selector option `<tr expandable-tree-row [columns]="cols"></tr>`
You just need some adjustments:
instead of injecting `ViewContainerRef` in your constructor, put in your expandable-tree-row template an `ng-template` with a template variable named `container` like:

```
<ng-template #container></ng-template>
```

And query it as `ViewContainerRef` with `@ViewChild` like:

```
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  private container: ViewContainerRef;
```